# Related activity records

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm-2011

So here is the thing : I created a custom entity "new_ligneContrat" which has a one-to-many
relationship with another custom entity "new_produit".

Here is the goal: when a new record of "new_ligneContrat" is created, it has to get the "new_produit" records of the "new_ligneContrat" before it. The plugin is built on "new_ligneContrat.

I was wondering if FetchExpression + last() could do it, but right now I haven't found the proper solution...

Thanks in advance !

**Edit1 :** We decided to go for a n to n relationship, so I did the following:

> 

```
QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression();
```

> ```
>                     query.EntityName = "new_produit";
>                     query.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("new_produitid");
>                     Relationship relationship = new Relationship();
>
>                     relationship.SchemaName = "new_new_lignecontrat_new_produit";
>                     RelationshipQueryCollection relatedEntity = new RelationshipQueryCollection();
>                     relatedEntity.Add(relationship, query);
>                     RetrieveRequest request = new RetrieveRequest();
>                     request.RelatedEntitiesQuery = relatedEntity;
>                     request.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("new_lignecontratid");
>                     request.Target = new EntityReference
>                     {
>                         Id = first.Id,
>                         LogicalName = first.LogicalName
>
>                     };
>
>                     RetrieveResponse response = (RetrieveResponse)service.Execute(request);
> ```

```
    if (((DataCollection<Relationship, EntityCollection>)(((RelatedEntityCollection)(response.Entity.RelatedEntities)))).Contains(new
> Relationship("new_new_lignecontrat_new_produit")) &&
> ((DataCollection<Relationship,
> EntityCollection>)(((RelatedEntityCollection)(response.Entity.RelatedEntities))))[new
> Relationship("new_new_lignecontrat_new_produit")].Entities.Count > 0)
>                         {
>                             response.Results.Remove("new_produitid");
>                             response["new_lignecontratid"] = new EntityReference(target.LogicalName, target.Id);
```

Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on which stage of the plugin execution your plugin is running in (pre-validation, pre/post-operation), one option is to execute a LINQ query that's dependent on the current time or the `CreatedOn` property of the new `new_ligneContrat` record and call the `First` method to get the latest `new_produit` record. I've included a mockup below.

```cs
DateTime d = DateTime.Now;
// or...DateTime d = targetEntity.Attributes["CreatedOn"].Value;

var usersSettings = (from lc in osc.CreateQuery<new_ligneContrat>()
                    join p in osc.CreateQuery<new_produit>() on lc.new_produitId equals p.new_produitId.Id
                    where lc.CreatedOn < d
                    orderby lc.CreatedOn descending
                    select p).First();
```

Comment: Thanks peter! EVentually we decided to go for a n to n relationship, so I did the following: